# Android contact query eliminate duplicates

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contacts

I have a very specific question about eliminating duplicates due to aggregated contacts from various added accounts on a device with my query against ContactsContract.Data

```
//
// (Mimetype == Phone OR Mimetype == Email)
// AND
// (
//   DisplayName LIKE searchQuery
//     OR
//   (Mimetype == Phone AND NormalizedPhone LIKE phoneNormalizedSearchQuery)
//     OR
//   (Mimetype == Email AND Email LIKE searchQuery)
// )
//
String selection = ""
        + "(" + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'" + " OR " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "')"
        + " AND "
        + "("
        + ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE '%" + searchQuery + "%'"
        + " OR "
        + "(" + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'" + " AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER + " LIKE '%" + phoneNormalizedSearchQuery + "%'" + ")"
        + " OR "
        + "(" + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'" + " AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS + " LIKE '%" + searchQuery + "%'" + ")"
        + ")";

Uri uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Contactables.VISIBLE_CONTACTS_ONLY, "true")
        .build();


return new CursorLoader(context, uri, CONTACTS_PROJECTION, selection, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
```

I have a free form search query that I want to partial match display name, phone, or email.  This is simple enough and works extremely well and is actually very fast (fast enough to highlight changing results realtime as the user types even with several thousand contacts).

Everything is great except the inability to eliminate duplicates.  When a user has multiple accounts on their device which result in aggregated contacts the result will have that phone number or email in the result of this query multiple times when the user has the same contact information across their added accounts.

**I do not want to post process the cursor** (no iterating over the cursor and creating a list in memory, syncing data into my own db, etc...).

Is there anyway to perform this query with the only difference being that the result will be limited to records with a distinct phone or email?

Comment: `limited to records with a distinct phone or email` what if you have two contacts with the same phone? would you want to display two results in this case?

Comment: You're right.  Contact table yes, but raw contact table no.  The problem is duplicate numbers from raw contacts that Google has already figured out how to aggregate.  I only want those ones returned once.  If Google didn't aggregate properly, or I really do have two contacts with the same number, it'd want to see two results.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not supported by `ContentResolver` APIs, and specifically not in `ContactsContract`. 
You might want to reconsider the post-processing option.